# Get value of combobox in mfc

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc

I'm a beginner in C++ (MFC) programming. 
So, I have two comboboxes: `IDC_COMBO1` and `IDC_COMBO2` .

How can I simply get the selected by user value from them?

I've read the MSDN, but I didin't understand the examples:

```
int nIndex = m_pComboBox->GetCurSel();
int nCount = m_pComboBox->GetCount();
```

How must I declare `m_pComboBox` ?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CString sData;
int nSel = m_NameListBox.GetCurSel();
if (nSel != LB_ERR)
{
   m_NameListBox.GetText(nSel, sData);
}
```

Please also use `DataExchange` MFC mechanism to map your control to a class variable:

```
void CUserSettingsDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_NAME_LISTBOX, m_NameListBox);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way you should declare m_pComboBox :

```
CComboBox *m_pComboBox1 = (CComboBox *) GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO1);
```

Now, you can use both the line to get the current selection and number of selections as shown in question.