# Referencing ComboBox Items after CBN_SELCHANGE C++ WIN32

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a Combo Box with 3 options in it for a start up menu. Of the options, 2 out of 3 of them will have some sort of effect on the other startup menu options. For example, if I select option 1, it would select a checkbox for another option, just so the user can see what each option in the combo box actually does before starting the program.

My issue right now is that I have used "ON_CBN_SELCHANGE" in my message map to detect an option change in the combo box which would execute a function, however, this function cannot access the values of my combo box. So if I were to try to use the "GetCurSel()" function, it keeps returning a value of 0. How do I go about solving this?

```
//Message map
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(COptionsDlg, CDialog)
     ON_CBN_SELCHANGE(600, COptionsDlg::OnOptionSelect)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

//This is the constructor for my combo box
for(int i = 0; i < m_OptionsList.size(); i++)
{
    CComboBox* ComboBox = new CComboBox();
    ComboBox->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | CBS_DROPDOWN, CRect(Left + 10, *Top, Right - 10, *Top + 300), this, 600);
    ComboBox->SetFont(DialogFont);

    for(int j = 0; j < m_OptionsList[i]->Labels.size(); j++)
    {
        ComboBox->AddString(m_OptionsList[i]->Labels[j]);
    }

}

//This is the function which executes after an option change occurs in the combo box
void COptionsDlg::OnOptionSelect(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < m_ComboBoxList.size(); i++)
    {
        int Index = m_ComboBoxList[i]->TheControl->GetCurSel();

        if(Index == 1 || Index == 0)
        {
            //Code that should run if those options are selected
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "constructor for my combo box" fragment appears to create a new `CComboBox` instance, populate it, then promptly leak it. It's never actually added to the window. It's not clear what relation, if any, it has with `m_ComboBoxList`

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified that m_ComboBoxList is a member which holds the list of dynamically created combo boxes (I have multiple in this startup menu).

Comment: Where do those combo boxes come from, and how, if at all, are they related to `CComboBox` instances created in the code shown?

Comment: They are created in the initialization function for the start up menu, there is a point later in the function which pushes each combo box into the vector "m_ComboBoxList".

Comment: That can't be. Outside the loop shown, `ComboBox` variable is out of scope and the allocated `CComboBox` instance has already been leaked. My guess is, the combo box you call `GetCurSel` on is different from one that actually appears on your window.

Comment: You were right, thank you so much! I wasn't pushing my ComboBox in the list with the other combo boxes, so I wasn't actually calling GetCurSel() on the correct combo box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selection needs to be stored in a member variable.
MFC provides a DataExchange mechanism to so this.

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310465/get-value-of-combobox-in-mfc)

more about [DataExchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-exchange?view=vs-2019)
hope this helps !